# Script function not found: myFunction

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I have a problem with my script. When I try to run the program an error message appears; "Script function not found: myFunction"

I need to know why is it not working or there is a better way to code what I am trying to do.

```
function onEdit(e){

var sheetName = "Summary1";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);


if(sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 8 && sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1).getValue() != 0)
{
  var sendMail = Browser.msgBox("Would you like to send an email", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if(sendMail == "Yes")
   {
    var subject = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 10).getValue();
    var body = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 11).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", subject, body);
   }
 }
 else if(sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 12 && sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1).getValue() != 0)
 {
  var sendMail1 = Browser.msgBox("Would you like to send an email", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if(sendMail1 == "Yes")
   {
    var subject1 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 13).getValue();
    var body1 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 14).getValue();
    var mail1 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 9).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(mail1, subject1, body1);    
   }
  }
  else if (sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 17 && sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1).getValue() != 0)
  {
   var sendMail2 = Browser.msgBox("Would you like to send an email", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
   if(sendMail2 == "Yes")
    {
     var subject2 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 15).getValue();
     var body2 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 16).getValue();
     var mail2 = sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 9).getValue();
     MailApp.sendEmail(mail2, subject2, body2);   
    }
   }  
}
```

Comment: There's no `myFunction` in your code. After you save your code, drop down will show the available functions, of which you should select one and then run your code.

Comment: Have you checked the triggers you've set up - they could be referencing the wrong function. Also running this from a simple `onEdit` trigger won't work as it won't have authorisation for `MailApp`.

Comment: Hello Ross, I've already given authorization for MailApp and it is still not working. Could you please run the script and tell me if it works?